# como orientar imagem usando intervation image

Tags: php, laravel, framework, imagemagick

Eu preciso de algo que oriente a imagem da forma correta e em seguida apareça.
Estou usando laravel e image intervation

```
 <?php 

$img = Image::make("{{$file->caminho}}{{$file->nome}}")-orientate(); 
               ?>

<img src="{{ $img }}"/>
```

Porém não consigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para quem pretende usar o image intervation e orientar as fotos, faça o seguinte

crie um link para a image, no meu caso eu estou passando o ID.

> a href="usuario/previewLarge/{{$file->id }}">

crie a rota:

> Route::get('usuario/preview/{fileId}', ['as' => 'files.preview', 'uses' => 'FilesController@preview'])->middleware('auth');

crie o controller

public function preview($fileId){

```
    $file = \App\Files::find($fileId);

    $finalPath = $file->caminho.'/'.$file->nome;

     $mime = mime_content_type($finalPath); //pega o tipo do arquivo e se for jpeg, fará o processo de orientação.

        if($mime == "image/jpeg")
        {

              return $image = Image::make($finalPath)
                    ->orientate()
                    ->resize(150, 200)
                    ->encode('data-url',0)->response();
        }
        else{

              return $image = Image::make($finalPath)->encode('data-url',0)->response();

        }

}
```

comigo funcionou, obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Tas a tentar usar *syntax* **blade** dentro do **php**, e falta `>` para acessares uma propriedade ou método.

```
<?php
     $img = Image::make($file->caminho . $file->nome)->orientate();
?>
```

Comment: qual é o output destas duas variáveis `$file->caminho $file->nome` ? verifica se geram um caminho valido para a imagem e se a imagem existe

Comment: se eu usar isto = <img src="{{ $file->caminho}}{{$file->nome}}"/>, eu tenho acesso a página. mas ela vem sem a orientação que preciso

Comment: Aconselhava-te a declarares a variavel no *controller* e retornavas para a view já orientada, assim será acessivel

Comment: <img src="photo/{{$file->caminho . $file->nome}}"/> (passando o caminho)

(controller)

Route::get('/photo/{img}', function()
 {
  

  $image = Image::make($img)->orientate();

 return $image->response();
 });

Eu tentei desta forma ele retorna o erro 404